# Using an ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, data-structures

I know how to use an ArrayList as an object like so:

```
ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
```

However, as part of an assignment, I'm supposed to fill out the provided method:

```
private static ArrayList<Token> parse(String s) { }
```

How am I supposed to work with the ArrayList (which I'm guessing is a parameter) in this case?

Comment: Please provide the full description of what you need to do

Comment: The intention is for you to break up the input String `s` into tokens, and then store each token in the `ArrayList` which you then return to the caller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ArrayList is the return value from the parse method. The only parameter is a String which you need to break up into tokens, place each token in the ArrayList and then return the list.

How you break up the list is specific to its initial format which you haven't mentioned. The example below shows how the method might look if the String was comma separated:

```
private static ArrayList<Token> parse(String s) {
    String[] tokens = s.split(",");
    return Arrays.asList(tokens);
}
```

See the API docs for split asList:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int)

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)

Comment: For now, this should be a comment (like the one I wrote).

Comment: Thanks, got it. I didn't go into further detail because I wanted to keep it concise and I just needed to know about the ArrayList

Answer (score 0):

You can use [java.util.Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) for this

```
 public List<String> parse(String s) {
        return Arrays.asList(s.split(" "));
    }
```

If you want to return List of `Token` and It your custom class then you have to make for loop like this

```
public List<Token> parse(String s) {
    List<Token> tokenList = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] strings = s.split(" ");
    int length = strings.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        tokenList.add(new Token(strings[i]));
    }
    return tokenList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert a `string` into a `ArrayList` try this:

```
public ArrayList<Character> convertStringToArraylist(String str) {
    ArrayList<Character> charList = new ArrayList<Character>();      
    for(int i = 0; i<str.length();i++){
        charList.add(str.charAt(i));
    }
    return charList;
}
```

Or if you need to split a string and on basis of some delimiter (example ','), then use

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(s.split(",")));
return myList;
```